# A simpler way to calculate flux through a hemisphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauss-law

[image]

The cross section of the hemisphere is perpendicular to the flux. And the flux is constant.

I thought I need to do a surface integral. I don't know how, but this integral is simplified by the constant E.

$$\int E \cdot dA$$
But because $E$ is constant for any $dA$, I can just take it out. 
$$E\int dA=EA$$
And $A=\frac{4\pi R^2}{2}$

But this is actually wrong, according to my textbook.

Somehow, you can just use the area of crossection, although there is nothing there, to compute the flux.

$$Flux=E*\pi R^2$$

Maybe, I am not understanding Gauss' Law correctly and fully.

If you place a charge right at the center of a sphere, the flux going through any hemisphere would always be half of the total flux going through the entire sphere.

Comment: -1. Unclear what you are asking. Your textbook has already told you how to solve this problem. What is your difficulty?

Comment: Why. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: BTW, thanks for leaving a explanation for your downvote. I got too much downvote for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes being a stickler for notation is helpful. The integral you want to do isn't $\int E \cdot dA$, but $\iint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A}$.

$d\vec{A}$ is the surface element of the sphere, $d\vec{A}=d\theta d\varphi r^2\sin\theta(\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$, and $\vec{E}=(E,0,0)$. If you do this integral over the proper bounds (theta from $0$ to $\pi$, and $\varphi$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$), you'll get $E\pi r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The flux is the same through the circle as through the hemisphere. There is no flux lost or gained in between, provided that there is no charge inside the hemisphere.