# Meaning of $d\vec{A}=d\theta d\varphi r^2\sin\theta(\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$

Tags: integration

I have seen to calculate $\int dA$ for a sphere, $dA$ is equal to:

$$d\vec{A}=d\theta d\varphi r^2\sin\theta(\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)).$$

I don't understand the meaning of the: $\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)$.

Link to original post:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/313108/185241

Comment: It's a vector, that points away from the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate vector $(\cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ is simply the unit vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is orthogonal to the unit sphere. It points away from the center of the sphere.

Comment: Ahh yes, silly me!